# Добавление объекта в массив объектов state при помощи onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Имеется некоторое состояние state компонента:

```
constructor() {
 super();
 UniqueID.enableUniqueIds(this);

 this.state = {
   users: [
     {id: this.nextUniqueId(), name: 'john', age: 20},
     {id: this.nextUniqueId(), name: 'peter', age: 30},
     {id: this.nextUniqueId(), name: 'jill', age: 25}
   ]
 }
 console.log(this.state) 
}
```

Также имеется два инпута: первый input с именем name, второй - с age.

Необходимо при событии onClick кнопки добавлять в уже существующий массив объектов users новый объект с нашими name и age.

```
addEvent = () => {
  this.setState(previousState => ({
    users: [...previousState.users, {id: this.nextUniqueId, name: '', age: ''}]
  }));
}

render() {
return (
  <div className="App"> 

  <div>
    <input
      className='test-input'
      placeholder = 'insert name'
    />

    <input
      className='test-input'
      placeholder = 'insert age'
    />

    <button
      onClick={this.addEvent}>
      Add obj
   </button>

  </div>
</div>
)}
```

Не могу понять, как связать инпуты и мой обработчик событий.

Answer (score 0):

```
addEvent = () => {
 this.setState(previousState => ({
   users: [...previousState.users, {id: this.nextUniqueId, name: previousState.name, age: previousState.age}]
 }));
}

<input
  className='test-input'
  placeholder = 'insert age'
  onChange={(e) => this.setState({name: e.target.value})}
  value={this.state.name}
/>
```

Аналогично для инпута возраста.